# I see "There are no review queues available to you" when clicking the review icon without any explanation

Tags: support, review, top-bar, review-suspension

This has appeared as the dropdown on my review queue button today:

> [image: review dropdown screenshot]

I can't find out anything about it.

- What does it mean?
- Why aren't there any review queues available to me?
- How long it's going to stay there?! :(

Comment: Where are you seeing this? What site? Screenshots will help.

Comment: You can't review until you reach 2k; you haven't reached that yet.

Comment: I've been reviewing Triage, First posts, and two others (I'll check) for ages. Did the policy change? Look: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2532190/mayersdesign?tab=activity&sort=reviews

Comment: @zondo - the "Access Review Queues" privilege is at 500 rep.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

It appears that you have hit a review ban - too many bad reviews (i.e. - rejected reviews).

This will expire in about an hour or so - be sure to review more carefully ;)

Answer (score 50):

You had too many bad / rejected reviews. This oftentimes is the result of failing the one's Stackoverflow places in the review queues to test your attention.

To see when your ban will be lifted visit the [Review Overview](https://stackoverflow.com/review) page.

Answer (score 19):

I discovered this week that there is one more situation where this happens:  if you exhaust your daily vote limit.  As soon as you do this, the review queues close, at least the basic ones that are available to lower-reputation users.  I suspect this is the case because one of the preferred tasks you can perform in most review queues is to upvote or downvote posts.

Comment: To ensure if it is because of this or because of bad reviews, you can just head to [the stack reviews page](https://stackoverflow.com/review) , and it will show what happened!

Answer (score 18):

The advice in the accepted answer ("review more carefully") is not actionable.

To uncover something actionable I went to the [review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review) as referenced in many comments here.  That page showed *one* bad edit, not *many*, and that the ban was for *four days*, not one hour.

When I looked into it a little more more I found that on that review I and one other reviewer had said "Looks OK", but three others said "Requires Editing".

Actionable advice: err on the side of enforcing high-quality posts, which is what all the guidance says.  In my particular case I'll be more inclined to vote "Requires Editing", which I now realize I haven't used very often.