# New review navigation does not tell review-banned users what happened or why

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, review-suspension

When I am review-banned, the direct effect is that when I click the review icon in the top-bar, I get this:

> [image: clicking the review button when review banned]

This doesn’t tell me anything about what's going on, just that all review queues have miraculously become unavailable to me. It doesn't show that it's because I've been banned, or why I've been banned, whether it's for failing audits or whether there is a custom message supplied by a moderator. Only when I new-tab-click that button, it takes me to `/review`, or when I manually navigate there, I get [the more informative message, as intended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228927/255554):

> [image: Review ban message only shown when opening review dropdown in a new tab, or manually going to /review]

This is confusing for review-banned users who use the dropdown in their standard workflow ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293479/255554)). I only performed the above test to reproduce the experience of a confused review-banned user on a site I moderate.

#### Please replace the dropdown message with something more informative in case of a review ban.

Comment: At first I thought there's nothing wrong with it since it implies that the user lost the privilege even though they has enough rep (well, there's only 1 possible reason: review ban). However, since the message & cooldown timer get lost, this is indeed a bigger problem (or the main issue).

Comment: @AndrewT.: *it implies that the user lost the privilege even though they has enough rep* – Not necessarily. It could be understood to mean that this is the default if all review queues happen to be empty (which never happens on some sites, so how would you know?). You also get the same message on a per-site meta if you are somewhere between 500 and 2 k reputation (or the respective beta equivalents).

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293479/there-are-no-review-queues-available-to-you-hey

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["There are no review queues available to you" - Hey?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293479/there-are-no-review-queues-available-to-you-hey)

Comment: @ShadowtheWelcomingWizard Not a duplicate. While I now do agree that that other post should be kept open, this one should be kept open too. The other one is a support question asking why this message appears, for which the answer is that one is review banned; this one is a bug report asking for it to be fixed.

Comment: Brought up again on MSO: [Triage needs to be fixed urgently, and users need to be notified upon receiving a review ban!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394498/triage-needs-to-be-fixed-urgently-and-users-need-to-be-notified-upon-receiving)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The review dropdown now let's the review suspended user know about their review suspension, and directs them to the `/review` page where a more detailed notice is available. Read about our [new improved experience for users with review suspensions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351118/51) for more info.

[image: Screenshot of the topbar review dropdown messaging during and after a review suspension is in effect]

---

> review suspended,
> don’t know why it was applied?
> go and click the link

Comment: Yaakov, I just saw at MSO complaint that [user can't see for how long they are suspended](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399714/839601). And [screen shot text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao2hH.png) seems to differ from one you show here. Is this some regression or intentional, or maybe I miss something?

Comment: Not a regression, @gnat. That's a suspension from suggested edits, which is completely separate from review queues. It's never shown the duration of the suspension. Mods just usually remember to put it in the message accompanying the suspension. Would certainly be nice if that UI can get improved as part of this project, but suggested edits may not be in scope.