# Add link to return to Review queues after reaching your daily reviews limit

Tags: feature-request, review, user-interface, hyperlinks

After clearing some review queue (i.e. there are no more posts to be reviewed for that queue, and you didn't reach your daily review limit for that queue yet), you get a page which looks like so:

> This queue has been cleared!
>
> If you’re looking for more to review, return to the Review queues main page.

[image]

The ***Review queues*** on that page, is actually a hyperlink to the site's `/review` page.

However, if for some review queue you reach your daily reviews limit, you don't get such page.  Instead you get a page which shows something like so (ABC and X varies):

> Thank you for reviewing ABC today; come back in X hours to continue reviewing.

Consider adding a similar link to the site's `/review` page on such daily reviews limit pages also, e.g. by changing ***continue reviewing*** to such hyperlink.

Comment: I'm guessing that this [happens on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4640431/pierre-vriens?tab=activity&sort=reviews&page=3) frequently, but we've **already** got a [duplicate request for an always present link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/346933/282094); regardless of the reason for its suppression. (Found from the similar [request on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394030/3648282), where the duplicity is clearer than our Meta duplicate).

Comment: I want this feature too.  Without the link, users won't know that they can keep the good times rolling! https://imgur.com/a/kHIWKBA

Comment: @mickmackusa merci for the support (and improving my post).