# Improve the user review ban experience

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, user-interface, review-suspension

*EDIT: While there are similarities with [New review navigation does not tell review-banned users what happened or why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303584/new-review-navigation-does-not-tell-review-banned-users-what-happened-or-why) (and please note that there are no answers to that question btw), I'm suggesting a different design and user journey.*

---

I'm not a UX expert but this doesn't look right to me:

[image]

The red dot usually is convention for *"new items since your last visit"*. However when you click, the message is rather confusing; it's not immediately clear that you have been banned from reviewing.

Initially I thought it was a bug but eventually I worked out (via the meta site) that I've been user-review banned. (I've been told why and I agree with the decision.)

I think the UI could be something like this instead:

[image]

When the user hovers the icon, a tooltip could say:

> You have been banned from reviews until 31st of March. Click to understand why

And the click would redirect the user to https://stackoverflow.com/review (or the appropriate review page for the network)

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394498/triage-needs-to-be-fixed-urgently-and-users-need-to-be-notified-upon-receiving?cb=1

Comment: Good idea, Stack Overflow has a pretty flat design though .. It should be just a diagonal single-colored line or whatever .. or the little checkbox becomes a cross. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog it does not; nobody gave an answer to that question

Comment: While that doesn't have an answer, here on Meta Stack Exchange, it's valid to close questions as duplicates of unanswered questions if the other question is proposing the same thing. To that end, the system allows voting to close as duplicates of unanswered questions, which is not allowed on main sites. That question is simply asking for "something more informative", which this constitutes. See [this section of our FAQ on how Meta Stack Exchange works](/a/47635/377214) and the last section of [our FAQ on duplicate closures](/a/10844/377214).

Comment: For those voting to close as a duplicate, this question is *not* a duplicate of the suggested dup-target. While the questions cover a similar area, this question is a *specific, explicit feature request*. The other question is a bug report.

Comment: @Makyen It's still asking for the same thing: something more informative in case of a review ban, which this constitutes. The specific thing it's proposing should be posted as an answer there.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog The other question is a bug report, not a feature request.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog While I haven't recently re-read the questions you linked, in a moderately brief scan there was nothing in them that said that feature requests should have answers on them suggesting alternate implementations. I'm not saying that's unreasonable, just that what you suggest is not documented as the appropriate action. In fact, I think that having answers on *feature requests* which suggest alternate implementations would be a good way to keep all similar such variations in one place.

Comment: @Makyen While this is tagged as a feature request, what this *really* is is a specific, proposed way of fixing the bug in the proposed dupe. This isn't really a *wholly separate* request from that one, when it comes to tracking the requests on SE's side.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Please note that I suggest solutions and not just "Please do something about it", so this ought to be different IMHO and should be taken into consideration. Perhaps you know better; in which case feel free to close.

Comment: That's exactly what I said; this is a specific, proposed way of fixing that bug. This is better served as an answer to that question rather than as a new question, since that will consolidate all discussion into one place and make it easier for SE to track this. (Even though this wouldn't really be an "answer" in the strict sense, here on Meta, answers that discuss questions are allowed in some cases, of which this is one.)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I don't think you can add tags such as `status-review` (which I believe help staff track such things) on answers. Is it entirely impossible to you that people can approach the problem in different ways hence allowing different questions? I shall close the question myself if you think otherwise.

Comment: Closed - thanks for your input.

Comment: I guess, if you're referring specifically to the requests themselves, they could be separate questions. However, this won't really work for reasons intrinsic to the system, as it makes it harder for SE to track the requests behind the scenes, as well as forking discussion into multiple places. I'm not saying your suggestion is *invalid*, just that it's not really a good way to put it forth due to these reasons. I do agree with your request. (Also, answers can be "tagged" with status tags - I've seen employees edit in tag markup `[tag:something]` into the bodies of answers.)