# Why I don't have any review queues?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, review

I have 700 reputation in StackOverflow right now. Once I've reached 500 rep I've got an opportunity to review first posts and do the triage. But now for some reason I can't do that. The inscription *"There are no review queues available to you"* is standing for several days.

I didn't get any message like "you were banned" or smth. And I didn't do anything wrong - there's only 1 bad flag (which was a mistake), I do not downvote every post, etc.

What can be a reason of that?

Comment: Do these answer your question? [New review navigation does not tell review-banned users what happened or why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303584/new-review-navigation-does-not-tell-review-banned-users-what-happened-or-why) and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293479/i-see-there-are-no-review-queues-available-to-you-when-clicking-the-review-ico